# Unable to create self referencing foreign key in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model `Region` and each `Region` can have sub-regions. Each sub-region has a field `parent_id` which is the id of its parent region. Here is how my model looks like

```
class Region(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'regions'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'schema_name'}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('regions.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Region', primaryjoin=('Region.parent_id==Region.id'), backref='sub-regions')
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    deleted_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

Bu when i try to do `db.create_all` i get this error `sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'regions.parent_id' could not find table 'regions' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'`

Why cant it find `regions` when i am specifying it in `__tablename__`? I am using flask-sqlalchemy version 1.0

EDIT --
i removed the line

```
__table_args__ = {'schema': 'schema_name'}
```

from my code and it works. Beats the hell out of me.

Comment: May be completely off... But are you sure that you want to inherit from `db.Model`? Examples for relationships in documentation inherit from `Base`.

Comment: I am using flask-sqlalchemy not sqlalchemy. have a look [here](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html) and even [here](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 15):

You must tell SQLAlchemy what the "remote side" of the relationship is, to distinguish between the current row and the row being joined to.  The relevant explanation is located partway into [this section of the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/self_referential.html#adjacency-list-relationships) on relationships.

The relationship might look like this:

```
parent = db.relationship('Region', remote_side=id, backref='sub_regions')
```

This is an example demonstrating a self-referential relationship:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
Base = declarative_base(engine)

session = Session()


class Region(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'region'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('region.id'), index=True)

    parent = relationship(lambda: Region, remote_side=id, backref='sub_regions')


Base.metadata.create_all()

r1 = Region(name='United States of America')
r2 = Region(name='California', parent=r1)

session.add_all((r1, r2))
session.commit()

ca = session.query(Region).filter_by(name='California').first()
print ca.parent.name
```

There will be many lines of SQL output since echo is on, and the script will print 'United States of America' at the end.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue with the schema name argument. What I changed to get it to work was to reference the table class directly in ForeignKey and relationships instead of using a string.
Example:

```
parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Region.id), index=True)

parent = relationship(lambda: Region, remote_side=id, backref='sub_regions')
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use a schema for any table, other tables that have foreign keys referencing those schema tables must provide the name of the schema. See [the docs here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#defining-foreign-keys)

```
class Table(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_1_name'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'my_schema'}

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

class AnotherTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_2_name'
    # Doesn't matter if this belongs to the same or different schema
    # __table_args__ = {'schema': 'my_schema'}

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    t1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('my_schema.table_1_name.id'))
    ...
```

Works for both SQLAlchemy and Flask-SQLAlchemy. Hope this helps. :D

Answer (score 4):

I only see slight differences from @davidism, but here's what works for me in straight SQLAlchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref

class Region(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'region'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('region.id'), index=True)
  sub_regions = relationship('Region', backref=backref('parent', remote_side='Region.id'))
```

As he points out I'm guessing you wont need the imports, but should prefix them with `db`, so something like:

```
class Region(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'region'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('region.id'), index=True)
  sub_regions = db.relationship('Region', backref=db.backref('parent', remote_side='Region.id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for SQLA 2.0+ and type hints:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    parent_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('node.id'))
    # Other columns ...

    # --- Relationships ---
    children: Mapped[list['Node']] = relationship(back_populates='parent', remote_side=[id])
    parent: Mapped['Node'] = relationship(back_populates='children')
```

It's important to set the `remote_side` so the SQLA knows how to link children. Then it's the usual reference via `back_referencing` (`backref` doesn't work well with type hints).