# Flask SQLalchemy - AttributeError: foreign_keys

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

While I try to execute my first GET request on the rest API I have this traceback. For the moment, there it nothing stored in the DB. The objective is to display an empty answer.

```
[2020-01-18 18:14:14,501] ERROR in app: Exception on /devices/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/api/routes/device.py", line 12, in get_list
    devices = Device.query.all()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 512, in __get__
    mapper = orm.class_mapper(type)
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 441, in class_mapper
    mapper = _inspect_mapped_class(class_, configure=configure)
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 420, in _inspect_mapped_class
    mapper._configure_all()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1337, in _configure_all
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3229, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1947, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 196, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1861, in do_init
    self._setup_join_conditions()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1941, in _setup_join_conditions
    can_be_synced_fn=self._columns_are_mapped,
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2246, in __init__
    self._determine_joins()
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2346, in _determine_joins
    consider_as_foreign_keys=consider_as_foreign_keys,
  File "<string>", line 2, in join_condition
  File "<string>", line 2, in _join_condition
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 130, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 918, in _join_condition
    a, a_subset, b, consider_as_foreign_keys
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 972, in _joincond_scan_left_right
    b.foreign_keys, key=lambda fk: fk.parent._creation_order
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 949, in __getattr__
    return self._fallback_getattr(key)
  File "/home/debian/Documents/projects/server-restapi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 923, in _fallback_getattr
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: foreign_keys
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2020 18:14:14] "GET /devices/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The referenced models are :

```
tags = db.Table('tag_device',
                db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True),
                db.Column('device_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('device.id'), primary_key=True)
                )


class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'device'
    id = db.Column(db.String(36), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    entity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id'), nullable=False)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    deviceGroup_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('deviceGroup.id'), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    layout_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('layout.id'), nullable=False)
    configuration = db.Column(db.Text)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('devices', lazy=True))
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    version = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Device %r>' % self.name


class Entity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    devices = db.relationship('Device', backref='entity', lazy=True)
    deviceGroups = db.relationship('DeviceGroup', backref='entity', lazy=True)
    medias = db.relationship('Media', backref='entity', lazy=True)
    playlists = db.relationship('Playlist', backref='entity', lazy=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', backref='entity', lazy=True)
    tagTypes = db.relationship('TagType', backref='entity', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Entity %r>' % self.name


class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    continent = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable=True)
    country = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable=True)
    state = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    zipcode = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    devices = db.relationship('Device', backref='location', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Location %r>' % self.name


class DeviceGroup(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'deviceGroup'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    entity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id'), nullable=False)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('deviceGroups', lazy=True))
    devices = db.relationship('Device', backref='device_group', lazy=True)
    children = db.relationship('DeviceGroup')
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('deviceGroup.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<DeviceGroup %r>' % self.name


class Layout(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'layout'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    path = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    devices = db.relationship('Device', backref='layout', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Layout %r>' % self.name


class TagType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tagType'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    entity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id'), nullable=False)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', backref='tagType', lazy=True)


class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    entity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id'), nullable=False)
    tagType_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tagType.id'), nullable=False)
```

For the one-to-many, many-to-many relations I used the official documentation https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/

Can you please help me to understand this error ?

R

Comment: Do you get a different result when adding a `backref` to your `DeviceGroup.children` relationship? I've never dealt with this error but it may indicate SQLAlchemy can't determine the mapping/join conditions between models.

Comment: First of all, thank you @djnz for helping me.

I have tried both methods for this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830147/unable-to-create-self-referencing-foreign-key-in-flask-sqlalchemy/47465718. 

Unfortunately, I still have the same error with this configuration : 

```
    children = db.relationship('DeviceGroup', backref=db.backref('parent', remote_side='DeviceGroup.id'))
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('deviceGroup.id'), index=True)
```

Comment: Please: Before considering posting google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. In code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. Emphasis here on the "minimal".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @djnz lead, I comment all the relationship between objects and uncomment one by one. One of the many-to-many relation was not using the good join table.

Thank you for your help,
R