# FLASK_SQLAlchemy : Is there a way to have a table relation with itself?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on making my own anonymous imageboard website and I want to make it so that the Post should have an Array of other Posts that came to it as a reply.

Something like this :

```
Post( id = 1, 
      comment = "Comment.", 
      replies = [Post1( id = 2, 
                        comment = "Comment.", 
                        replies = [and its own replies.]),

                 Post2( id = 3, 
                        comment = "Comment.", 
                        replies = [and its own replies.])])
```

---

Anyway, here is the code (That doesn't work) ::

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
defim = 'https://i.ibb.co/bLYtSY3/outrage3-B.png'

class Post(db.Model):
    board = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable = False)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
    img = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False, default = defim)
    loc = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False, default = "Unknown.")
    cmnt = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    life = db.Column(db.Integer, default = 108)
    replies = db.relationship('Post', backref = 'post', lazy = True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.id}', '{self.time}', '{self.img}', '{self.loc}', '{self.cmnt}', '{self.life}', '{self.replies}')"
```

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to get this done, if you have something better then please do tell.

Comment: Did you check https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/self_referential.html?

Comment: Very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830147/unable-to-create-self-referencing-foreign-key-in-flask-sqlalchemy

Comment: Thanks @funnydman!! Sorry for the late reply. I had stopped coming back to this question because I never got any replies.